# osm data import failed with osm2pgsql and windows

Tags: osm2pgsql

I am trying to import a .pbf file into my postgres/postgis database. I am using the following command line for importing the osm file

> C:\Users\Toton>osm2pgsql -c -d osmgb -U postgres -H localhost -S
>   C:\osm2pgsql\os m2pgsql-master\default.style
>   E:\osmgb\great-britain-latest.osm.pbf

Its returning the following error

> release notes: 'Windows version built by Dominik Perpeet
>   (http://www.customdebug.com/osm2pgsql/index.html)'  Using projection
>   SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)  Error reading style file line 151
>   (fields=4) flag 'phstore' is invalid in non-hstore mode Error
>   occurred, cleaning up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create hstore extension in your PostGIS database run SQL query "CREATE EXTENSION hstore" and enable hstore option in osm2pgsql import command adding key "--hstore"